# Loop to get user data

Tags: php, codeigniter

> I can't put real code here because is very long and will be hard to
>   explain.

I have **users** table in database and I have **data** table in database too.

So, to get the user data I'll pass user_id as parameter. Like this:

```
public function get_user_data($user_id) {

}
```

But. I can only get 1 data per "request". (*Keep reading)*

```
public function user_data() {
   $getUsers = $this->db->get('users');
   foreach($getUsers->result_array() as $user)
   {
      $data =  $this->get_user_data($user->ID);
      var_dump($data); // Only return 1 data;
   } 
}
```

But, I guess that have an way to "bypass" this but I don't know. I'm having trouble thinking.

As I said, I want to "bypass" this, and be able to send multiple user IDs, my real function do not accept that by default and **can't** be changed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide your database table structure. You need to use JOIN

Comment: does your data table has multiple data of same user id ?

Comment: try to `var_dump()` outside the foreach

Comment: Why not you are trying `where_in`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
foreach($getUsers->result_array() as $user)
{

$data =  $this->get_user_data($user->ID);

var_dump($data); // Only return 1 data;
}
```

to this

```
foreach($getUsers->result_array() as $user)
{
$data[] =  $this->get_user_data($user->ID);    
}
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Hi. I try to do this before, return empty arrays.

Comment: Is your function get_user_data() returns any data ?

Comment: Basicaly, i need an way to execute get_user_data() with different names. But, imagine an DB with 400 accounts, will be....Oh god!

Comment: Rakesh...With this method above, return empty data...Without, return just one result, it's an limitation of my function and I can't change that .But I've been thinking if there is a way to bypass this, as I said.

Comment: You want data without calling this get_user_data() in user_data() method are you saying this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming at sending more data to the function, you always need to make signature change of your function as one of the below :

```
 function get_user_data() {
      $args = func_get_args();    
      /** now you can access these as $args[0], $args[1] **/
 }
```

Or

```
function get_user_data(...$user_ids) {         
      /** now you can access these as $user_ids[0], $user_ids[1] **/
}
// Only higher version of PHP
```

But I am not sure how you will handle returning data.

EDIT: Yes, then in the function, you can collect data in array and return an array of data from function.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change in your function from `where` to `where_in` I think you will get an easy solution.

```
public function get_user_data($user_ids)
{
     // your db code 
     $this->db->where_in('ID',$user_ids); //replace where with where_in
}


public function user_data() 
{
    $getUsers = $this->db->get('users');
    foreach($getUsers->result_array() as $user)
    {
        $user_ids[] =  $user->ID;
    } 
    $this->get_user_data($user_ids);
 }
```